# Connection to access database fails while executing the visual studio vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, visual-studio-2017

I have coded in vb.net & connected to access database. The connection to the database stops once I start running the visual studio project.

Kindly get me out of this issue.

Comment: You should write a detailed question, with this information is very difficult to help you. You will not get many answers, and may get downvoted. Take a look at the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read this article about how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then "refactor" your question...:)

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] and take the [tour]. Thanks.